# Bash if doesn't match the content

Tags: bash

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
content="My sms content"
nomer="My Phone number"
if [[ -n "$content" && -n "$nomer" ]]; then
echo "it passes the first filter..."
    if [ "$(echo $content| awk '{print tolower($0)}')" = "My sms content" ]; then
    echo "Yes it matches the content"
    else
    echo "the variable doesn't match the content"
    fi
fi
```

It displays nothing when I run the code. What I want is that it displays `Yes it matches the content` How do I do that?

**UPDATE** as @BlueMoon answer I updated my code but it still says `the variable doesn't match the content` 
I want it to match the content

Comment: miya kalpa @JID deleting my comment

Comment: Now it doesn't match the `content` string because `tolower` converts it to lower case and your string `"My sms content"` has upper case `M` in `My`. So it doesn't match.

Comment: As a side note: to lowercase the content of `content`, you should quote `content`: `if [ "$(echo "$content" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')" = "my sms content" ]; then ...`. Otherwise you'll be subject to pathname expansion if `content` contains glob characters. Yet, there's a much better way to lowercase the content of a variable in recent versions of Bash: `${content,,}`. So it's much better to write: `if [[ "${content,,}" = "my sms content" ]]; then ...`.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the problem of this passing *only if both strings are empty:*

```
if [[ -z "$content" && -z "$nomer" ]]
```

(you probably meant `-n` which is the *non-empty* variant), you also have the problem that a string converted to lower-case will *never* contain a capital `M`:

```
if [ "$(echo $content| awk '{print tolower($0)}')" = "My sms content" ]
```

(you probably meant `"my sms content"`).

In any case, if you're using a relatively modern version of `bash`, it has case conversion built in so you don't have to use external processes. The following transcript shows the four possibilities, upper-case first, upper-case all, lower-case first and lower-case all:

```
pax> word='abcde' ; echo ${word^}
Abcde
pax> word='abcde' ; echo ${word^^}
ABCDE
pax> word='ABCDE' ; echo ${word,}
aBCDE
pax> word='ABCDE' ; echo ${word,,}
abcde
```

I gather the rationale here was that the caret `^` points up while the comma `,` points down. So you can simply use:

```
if [[ "${content,,}" == "my sms content" ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`-z` tests for being zero length. So what you're comparing is to check that both strings are empty.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
if [[ -z "$content" && -z "$nomer" ]]; then
```

says if both strings are of *non-zero* then do it.

What you probably meant is if both are non-empty:

```
if [[ -n "$content" && -n "$nomer" ]]; then
```

From manual:

```
   -z string
          True if the length of string is zero.
   string
   -n string
          True if the length of string is non-zero.
```